# Exposed Form in Block Missing?

Tags: views

I'm trying to create a view based on a Solr search index that includes a search form in a block. The view seems to be working based on the preview I see when editing the view. I have set "Exposed form in block: Yes" and "Exposed form style: Basic". The block is assigned to a region, and the block itself is rendered appropriately when the page is displayed. The problem I'm having is that the form is not displayed in the block. I see the block title, but no form and no button. What might I be missing here?

Comment: Sorry, this is with Drupal 8.7.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. In addition to setting "Exposed form in block: Yes", I had to check the "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it" option for my "Search: Fulltext search" filter. The search form was properly displayed once that option was set.

Comment: If this is your answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Exposed filters on blocks will only work if you've enabled ajax on the view. Try enabling that and your filters should appear

Comment: I set "Use AJAX" to  "Yes" under the Advanced settings. The search form still isn't visible in the block.